# Facebook API not returning all photos on a page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm trying to grab all photos posted by other users on a page, but for some reason facebook seems to skip seemingly random photos. I'm not sure if it was happening a few days ago, but if it was I didn't notice it. Here's the FQL Query I'm using:

```
SELECT post_id, actor_id, created_time, permalink,
   message, attachment,
   comments.count
FROM stream
WHERE source_id=me()
AND filter_key='others'
AND attachment.fb_object_type='photo'
AND created_time > #{Time.now.to_i - 60*60*24*5}
ORDER BY updated_time DESC
LIMIT 0, 500
```

Please excuse the ruby time method in there - it works without that line, even in the api explorer. Also, the API token is for the page, so the `me()` method works properly. It seems to skip random photos, even though they are all public and should be returned. Is this a bug or is there something wrong with the query? If I could do this in the graph API instead, I would love to know how.

Comment: Are you sure the users posting those photos haven't disabled platform? how many photos are you finding aren't returned?

Comment: It's a server side app, not a user accessible app, so I don't know if users could disable it. The ones that don't show up are always the same, so it could be that. Currently there is only about 1 out of 10 not returning